# TextView's lag on Android

Tags: android, textview

Here is my code. The `Textviews` are separated into two groups and one group should be better than the other

```
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(predictionFlag)
            {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                predictionFlag = false;
            }

            int x = 0;

            do
            {
                if(x != 0)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                      {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                }

                Location predicationPoint = DOTGpsAppUtils.predictionAlgorithm(latitude, longitude, 1, 100);

                double predictionLongitude = (longitude + predicationPoint.getLongitude())/2;
                double predictionLatitude = (latitude + predicationPoint.getLatitude())/2;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneHundredMillisecondLatitude);
                textView.setText(Double.valueOf(predictionLatitude).toString());

                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneSecondCalculatedPointLongitude);
                textView.setText(Double.valueOf(predictionLongitude).toString());


                if(x == 9)
                {
                    longitude = predictionLongitude;
                    latitude = predictionLatitude;
                }

                System.out.println(x);

                ++x;
            }while(x < 10);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startingPointLongitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(location.getLongitude()).toString());

            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startingPointLatitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(location.getLatitude()).toString());

            textView =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneSecondCalculatedPointLongitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(longitude).toString());

            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneSecondCalculatedLatitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(latitude).toString());

            ++y;

            System.out.println("Thread Count:" + y);

        }
```

I'm wondering why on the android screen does not update the  `R.id.oneHundredmilliesecand` faster and the other `textviews`. Because I think it should be able to update the screen faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all of this is happening on the UI thread.

There's no chance for the framework to run and actually redraw the whole thing as you're using up the UI thread with sleeps.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep(100)` blocks the UI thread and no UI elements can be updated.